# Second Cascading Select is not getting populated correctly on change

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

When I change the parent dropdown for the first time, the cascading dropdown is getting populated correctly. When I change the parent dropdown for the second time, the value is not getting populated. The third time, the parent dropdown is changed, the previous value is getting populated.

But in the console, the correct data is getting populated. The only issue is it is not getting bound in the UI.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Could you please provide us with a plunkr so we can see your code and try to figure it out? We cant see your error just by your explanation.

Comment: I have updated code in plunkr. but not ble to make it work.The code is in https://plnkr.co/edit/3u4zUFgj4NZALxBycKTq?p=preview